# What will be the eventual result of the Milky Ways future mergers?

Tags: expansion, supermassive-black-hole, galaxy-cluster

I am wondering, after the Milky Way merges with Andromeda and other near by dwarf galaxies and globular clusters, will it then merge with galaxies in the Virgo cluster and even Laniakea? And if so will the eventual result be one super giant galaxy or smaller but still large galaxies orbiting each other whilst the rest of the universe has expanded out of sight?

Edit: during my research I have had contradicting information on what will happen some say within each cluster, galaxies will all merge to one giant galaxy, whilst others disagree?

Comment: The OP did post this on Physics SE, however I suggested posting here on Astronomy SE so please don't blame the OP for cross-posting in this case.  The Physics SE version of the question is [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/544930/what-will-be-the-eventual-result-of-the-milky-ways-future-mergers).